# FME - Specify schema name in PostgreSQL database writer (ArcSde)

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, arcgis, fme

I am attempting to transfer data from a file geodatabase into an enterprise geodatabase (PostgreSQL) using FME. By default, the writer copies it into either the "public" schema or the "sde" schema. However, I aim to copy the data into a schema of my choice (which is “test” in this example). Although I've attempted to add the schema name before my table name using a dot, as suggested in an older post on this forum, I am still encountering errors.

Error: The error message from ArcObjects is: {DBMS table not found} [stormwater.test._2017_2018_O_M_Assessments]}

The following items exists:

```
PostgreSQL Database Name: stormwater

File Geodatabase Name: _2017_2018_O_M_Assessments

Schema Name: test
```

The writer is set to **create the table if it doesn't exist** (which in my case doesn't exist already).

Please see the attached image for reference.

[image: Workflow Image]

Comment: 1) Do not use images, copy and paste as text into your question. 2) Is there a `test` schema in the database? 3) Does the table exist in the database? **Add answers as update to question text**.

Comment: You have not answered whether the table exists? This is important as from what is visible in the error message, the table cannot be found.